# filter on web search is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a filter of my website.

I have 4 tables:

```
-----------------
content_ref_table
-----------------
content_id(pk) | title | description | content_url | thumb_icon | category_id(fk) | course_id(fk) | subject_id(fk)    

-----------------
course_ref_table
-----------------
course_id(pk) | course

-----------------
subject_ref_table 
-----------------
subject_id(pk) | subject  

-----------------  
cateory_ref_table  
-----------------
category_id(pk) | category
```

I have 3 filters right now with select tag:

- category
- courses
- subjects

A user can filter using one or more filters.

So what query I should use to show more relevant data ?

Comment: you can use  `COALESCE()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the `id` of those (3) filters, you can use `WHERE` and `LIKE` clauses. Here's a start:

```
$category = !empty($_POST["category"]) ? $_POST['category'] : "";
$course = !empty($_POST["course"]) ? $_POST['course'] : "";
$subject = !empty($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST['subject'] : "";

$query = "SELECT * FROM content_ref_table 
          WHERE category_id LIKE '%".$category."%'
            AND course_id  LIKE '%".$course."%'
            AND subject_id  LIKE '%".$subject."%'";
```

There are different ways on how to achieve your goal. It can be made also with the PHP `if`s/ `while`s/ etc loops. You should consider the speed and security too for querying.

---

**[UPDATE]**

If you're looking for names, then you should do some joining if you're outsourcing data from other connected tables. For example:

```
$category = !empty($_POST["category"]) ? $_POST['category'] : "";
$course = !empty($_POST["course"]) ? $_POST['course'] : "";
$subject = !empty($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST['subject'] : "";

$query = "SELECT content_ref.title FROM content_ref_table 
          LEFT JOIN category_ref_table ON content_ref_table.category_id = category_ref_table.category_id 
               AND category_ref_table.category LIKE '%".$category."%'
          LEFT JOIN course_ref_table ON content_ref_table.course_id = course_ref_table.course_id 
               AND course_ref_table.course LIKE '%".$course."%'
          LEFT JOIN subject_ref_table ON content_ref_table.subject_id = subject_ref_table.subject_id 
               AND subject_ref_table.subject LIKE '%".$subject."%'";
```

You don't have to use `WHERE` clause if the data you're looking for is from a joined table, you can always put that condition along with the join clauses but it's not always the same effect with `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: no i won't get id of those filters,i will only get name value,for eg : category:'ug' ,course='b.com',subject='eco'

Comment: @parvez I made an update to the answer above. Kindly check it.